# Prevent monitor from powering on

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7, windows-vista

I'm turning off the monitor using `SendMessage(HWND_BROUADCART, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORRPOWER, 2)`.

That works, but the monitor turns back on when someone touches the keyboard or mouse. I tried to get rid of this using the DevicePowerSetDeviceState function with DEVICEPOWER_CLEAR_WAKEENABLED for the keyboard and mouse: it returns no error, but has no effect either.

How can I prevent the monitor from powering back on in Vista and Windows7?

Comment: There used to be some handy ways to make monitors explode, but sadly the hardware guys have fixed that stuff...for now

Comment: @John Seigel: Agree with you on the why question. Possible why in case the OP doesn't answer: Something like remote-control software i.e. LogMeIn/VNC/RDP etc.

Comment: Yes, it is for remote control software

Comment: @Billy: Okay, still kind of confused. I would think that any remote control software would allow the control to be overridden at the physical workstation. What would be an example use case for preventing monitor power-on?

Comment: @Jon: Not all remote software allows this. LogMeIn's free software for example allows one to configure whether the physical user should be able to override the machine or not.

Comment: For example, the teacher can turn off monitors of students to make them pay attention to what he's saying (it is real use-case, in fact)

Comment: Using WM_BROADCAST is the WRONG way to turn off the monitor, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/06/13/629451.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Connect all monitors to the same outlet (or two, three, ... outlets if you have many monitors) and put a power switch on the teacher's desk.

Not all problems should be solved by software.

Comment: +1: The problem will be definitily solved when the power surge induced by the multiple physical on/off will break all the monitors :P

Comment: Good point, but there is probably a good solution for that.  Isn't there a www.currentoverflow.com site or something similar :-)